# Annotation processor cannot get annotation for type variable

Tags: java, gradle, annotation-processing

This method:

```
public static <T, @Nullable R> void foo(@Nullable Object obj, T t, @Nullable List<? extends @Nullable R> r)
```

annotationProcessor (by gradle) cannot read the `@Nullable` for `R` (in `<T, @Nullable R>` and `List<? extends @Nullable R>`), but can read for `@Nullable Object obj`.

Why and how to solve?

This is a portion of the code:

```
List<? extends TypeParameterElement> typeParameterElements = element.getTypeParameters();
        if (typeParameterElements != null && !typeParameterElements.isEmpty()) {
            methodInfo.setTypeParams(typeParameterElements.stream().map(it -> buildTypeName(it.asType())).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        }

private String buildTypeName(TypeMirror typeMirror) {
    String annotations = "";
    // Here! Cannot get @Nullable for type variable(R)!
    List<? extends AnnotationMirror> annotationMirrors = typeMirror.getAnnotationMirrors();
    if (!annotationMirrors.isEmpty()) {
        annotations = annotationMirrors.stream().map(i -> i.toString() + " ").collect(Collectors.joining());
    }
    if (typeMirror instanceof DeclaredType) {
        DeclaredType declaredType = (DeclaredType) typeMirror;
        List<? extends TypeMirror> args = declaredType.getTypeArguments();
        if (args.isEmpty()) {
            return annotations + declaredType.asElement().toString();
        }
        String argsNames = args.stream().map(this::buildTypeName).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
        return annotations + declaredType.asElement().toString() + "<" + argsNames + ">";
    }
    //Never get WildcardType, why?
    if (typeMirror instanceof WildcardType) {
        WildcardType wildcardType = (WildcardType) typeMirror;
        TypeMirror up = wildcardType.getSuperBound();
        if (up != null) {
            return "? super " + buildTypeName(up);
        }
        TypeMirror sp = wildcardType.getExtendsBound();
        if (sp != null) {
            return "? extends " + buildTypeName(sp);
        }
    }
    if (typeMirror instanceof IntersectionType) {
        IntersectionType intersectionType = (IntersectionType) typeMirror;
        List<? extends TypeMirror> bounds = intersectionType.getBounds();
        String boundNames = bounds.stream().map(this::buildTypeName).collect(Collectors.joining(" & "));
        return annotations + typeUtils.asElement(intersectionType) + " extends " + boundNames;
    }
    if (typeMirror instanceof TypeVariable) {
        TypeVariable typeVariable = (TypeVariable) typeMirror;
        TypeMirror lower = typeVariable.getLowerBound();
        if (lower != null && !(lower instanceof NullType)) {
            return annotations + typeMirror + " super " + buildTypeName(lower);
        }
        TypeMirror upper = typeVariable.getUpperBound();
        if (upper != null && !(upper instanceof NullType) && !Objects.equals("java.lang.Object", upper.toString())) {
            return annotations + typeMirror + " extends " + buildTypeName(upper);
        }
    }
    return annotations + typeMirror;
}
```

Comment: The signature doesn't make sense. You declare that `R` is some type variable, and you also declare there that it is nullable. When you use R, you repeat yourself. Pick a side, either nullability is declared where you declare a typevar, __or__ it is declared where you _use_ a typevar. The common thing to do is the latter, so as to for example allow differentiation (have a sig where some type is used, sometimes nullable, sometimes not). I don't think your question is relevant: You don't want that annotation there in the first place, hence, 'how do I read it?' is a moot point.

Comment: @rzwitserloot This is just an example for testing annotationProcess. What I want to solve is the problem that annotationProcessor cannot get the annotation of typevar. Even if I remove @Nullable in the `<R>` declaration, the annotation in `? extends @Nullable R` still cannot be obtained.

Comment: There are 3 __completely__ different constructs here. [A] `@Nullable String foo` - this is a seemingly ambiguous annotation: Is it on `String`, or is it on parameter `foo`? The spec has clear answers, though. [B] `List<? extends @Nullable String>` - annotations on types in generics usage, and [C] `<@Nullable T>` - annotations on typevar _declarations_. C and B look similar but are as different as guns and grandmas.